# How to center 'Getting Data' on mobile screen

Tags: javascript, html, mobile, mobile-safari

While developing a site for many browsers, mobile and desktop, I've noticed that the following CSS works nicely to center a loading div.

```css
img.loading1 {
    position:absolute;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-16px;
    top:50%;
    margin-top:-16px;
    z-index:10
}
.loading2 {
    color:#006BB2;
    position:absolute;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:0px;
    top:40%;
    z-index:5
}
.loading3 {
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    background-color:lightgrey;
    opacity:0.85
}
```

```html
<div id="container" style="position:relative">
    ...content ommitted...
    <div id="loading" style="display:none">
        <div class="loading3"></div>
        <img class="loading1" src="images/loader-ajax.gif" width="32" height="32">
        <span class="loading2" id="getting">Getting your request...</span>
    </div>
    ...content ommitted...
```

The div's display gets set to 'block' and the 3 items center great.

However, on a mobile screen, while the horizontal is right on, the vertical position could be off-screen depending on the height of the 'containing' div.

Is it possible to find the center of the screen and position the image and span there with Javascript?

**Edit 1:** Must the height of the loading div be set to be the height of the screen for this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Related info:**

Every absolutely-positioned element is positioned relative to a container. The default container is the body tag.

If no dimensions are specified, an element with absolute position is shrink-wrapped to the size of its content. When calculating the size in JavaScript, the value returned is whatever the current size happens to be, based on the content it contains. The element will not have the same size as its parent unless the width or height is explicitly set to 100%.

**Without using jQuery:**

Get the x and y location of the container element (relative to the viewport), the width and height of the viewport, and the width and height of the element.

Set the `top` to half the viewport height, minus the container y position, minus half the element height.
Set the `left` to half the viewport width, minus the container x position, minus half the element width.

```
// Center an absolutely-positioned element in the viewport.
function centerElementInViewport(el, container) {

    // Default parameters
    if ((typeof container == 'undefined') || (container === null))
        // By default, use the body tag as the relative container.
        container = document.body;

    // Get the container position relative to the viewport.
    var pos = container.getBoundingClientRect();

    // Center the element
    var left = ((window.innerWidth >> 1) - pos.left) - (el.offsetWidth >> 1);
    var top = ((window.innerHeight >> 1) - pos.top) - (el.offsetHeight >> 1);
    el.style.left = left + 'px';
    el.style.top = top + 'px';
}
```

Here's a [jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Matt_Coughlin/R8JGT/6/). If there are problems running it in jsfiddle, try this [standalone demo](http://www.forestpath.org/test/misc/center-in-viewport.html).

Tested it in IE7/8/9, Firefox, Chrome, Safari, and Safari Mobile (iOS). The only thing found to cause a problem so far is if the absolutely-positioned element has a margin (which this function does not support at present).

Haven't tested in a responsive design yet.

**Note:** Be careful not to call this function when the page first loads. If the browser was scrolled or zoomed and then reloaded, the page may not have been rescrolled or zoomed back to where it was yet, and the resulting position would be incorrect. Setting a timer of 100 msec before calling the function seemed to work (allowing the browser time to rescroll and rezoom the page).

Comment: I was having trouble linking the viewport and position in container element. This seems the most promising. It will take me a few minutes to interpret the 2nd paragraph. Thanks for suggesting.

Comment: Added sample code. It calculates the size of the element, rather than using negative margins equal to half the size. Should be more flexible this way.

Comment: Thanks. I still need to know if the loading div needs a height. In my code above, it has no height. So when you suggest, 'calculate the size of the element', in my head, it has no size. At the time of asking the element's size is the same as the container because (I think) of the '<div id="container" style="position:relative">' and `.loading[1,2 & 3] { position: absolute;...}`

Comment: No, the loading div does not have to have a height. I tested it with and without explicit sizes and it seemed to work fine in all browsers. Added info about this to the answer.

Comment: Realized that the same approach can be used whether the element is positioned relative to the body tag or relative to a container. It's far simpler and safer this way. Updated the sample code to reflect this. Tested in IE7/8/9, FF, Safari, Chrome.

Comment: Thanks! The original code does work great in the browsers you mentioned. I am needing the solution particularly in mobile browsers. What if the container is (eg) 1000px high? How does the 'Getting data...' & image **not** get displayed in the center of the body, yet below the bottom of the screen at 500px (roughly centered) on a 480px screen (iPhone, Android, etc) ??

Comment: It seems to work fine, even on mobile browsers, with large or small containers, on large or small pages. It works based on relative distance from the viewport (the currently displayed part of the page, aka the screen), not on page size or container size. It uses getBoundingClientRect() for this, which is what does the magic. Try it out for yourself, using the updated code above. I added a link to a demo in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

in my exeprience this is hard to do with html/css

the easiest way i have found is using Javascripts innerHeight property

code could look like:

```
if (window.innerHeight) {
  var loadingHeight = document.getElementById('loading').offsetHeight;
  document.getElementById('loading').style.top = (((window.innerHeight/2)-loadingHeight) + "px");
}
```

you can set the horizontal position using the same method but replacing the height, offsetHeight and window.innerHeight methods with the respective width options, they are all well documented on the web

Comment: A good suggestion. Do I need to set the height of <div id="loading"> to be the innerHeight? In other words, how does the content of the loading div get placed in the center of the _screen_ ? In my example code, this div has NO height dimension.

Comment: so yes this takes a little math

there key is

(window.innerHeight/2)-THE HEIGHT OF YOUR DIV + "px"

you can either set a height property, use developer tools to measure it (which i wouldnt suggest it would probably cause you cross browser problems) or use javascript to measure the height of the div  and set it as a variable just before setting the "top" css property, i will update my answer with some extra example code for you

Answer (score 0):

Use [`position: fixed`](http://davidwalsh.name/css-fixed-position) with fix `width` & `height`.

Comment: Using `position:fixed` to center content can be tricky if the content is in an IFrame (e.g., a Facebook app). If the user scrolls the parent page but not the IFrame, the resulting location of the centered content may be different than expected.

Comment: Does the loading div need to have a height for this to work? Thanks

Comment: Yes, not best with iframes, but in this example there is no iframe.

Comment: You only need fix height, if you want to center the div vertically too.