# Always center div in the middle of screen

Tags: javascript, jquery

My object is to have popup appear on the center of screen. Everything works fine with default zoom on PC and tablets with "Matt Coughlin" [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11364959/how-to-center-getting-data-on-mobile-screen?answertab=active#tab-top), but things starts to break when zooming in.

Popup div jumps out of the screen most of the times and therefore is unusable on smaller devices.

I have tried to find a way for a while now and nothing really works. Is there even a way to get center of a screen, not page?

Basically when you press open popup, it aligns center of the area. If you scroll it a bit right and repress open popup, then result is the same, but while zooming in mobile devices, then it won't work anymore. Code example, which aligns popup in the middle of screen (el is the popup element)

```
var pos = document.body.getBoundingClientRect();
var left = ((window.innerWidth >> 1) - pos.left) - (el.width() >> 1);
var top = ((window.innerHeight >> 1) - pos.top) - (el.height() >> 1);
```

[JSFIDDLE EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ceujq/3/)

Comment: can you post some code or jsfiddle ?

Comment: Backing up Adidi on this one.  There are a lot of factors that will change the answer to this question.  Is the div fixed width?  Does it have variable content?  Can it be fixed, or should it scroll with the page?  If you can provide a basic example of what you're trying to do, we can help fill in the blanks.

Comment: added example and most importnant lines.

Comment: so this issue is on tablets right? not so much on desktops? asking for reason.

Comment: Problem doesn't occur with PC, it's only with smart devices.

Comment: what about setting the attribute data-position-to="window" on an anchor that calls your popup?

Comment: I really don't like that idea, because it will guide page to another location instead of having popup on the same location.